# How to escape URL but keep the square brackets around IPv6 address unchanged

Tags: java, javascript

I have a URL which I need to percent-encode using Java or Javascript.

I can't know in advance if the URL will or will not include protocol, port or path. Also I can't know if the host will be a name, IPv4 address or IPv6 address.

This URL:

```
  http://[fc00::90:90]/path/to/[file].txt
```

has two sets of square brackets. The first is ok, needed for the IPv6 address. But the second should be percent-escaped. So the URL after escaping should be:

```
http://[fc00::90:90]/path/to/%5Bfile%5D.txt
```

How can I escape the second pair but not the first pair?

I thought `URI.toASCIIString` is the obvious solution, but it doesn't like the brackets in the file name and throws

`java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 29: http://[fc00::90:90]/path/to/[file].txt`

There is also an option to parse the URL into its components and escape only the path part, but I prefer not to do that if that's possible.

Can anyone suggest a solution using Java or Javascript?
Thanks.

Comment: While storing file name change `[` to `%5B`. When you display it to user change `%5B` to `[` but back link will be `http://[fc00::90:90]/path/to/%5Bfile%5D.txt`

Comment: What you suggest is to do `url.replace("[", "%5B").replace("]", "%5D")`, right?
That's a possibility but I was hoping for a way to escape all chars that may be a problem, including spaces, quotes etc.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuri before creating URL pass file name to `encodeURI` function and get converted filename

Comment: I would like to avoid parsing the URL to its components (protocol, host, port etc.), if that's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found for this problem does include parsing the URL to parts, but at least it's done using the `java.net.URL` Java library.

`java.net.URL` does not have a function to escape special chars. `java.net.URI`, which does have such functionality, won't accept un-escaped square brackets in the URL path. The following solution combines the two to solve the problem:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
String escapedURL = uri.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not encode the whole url using one function.
Every part of the url allows different characters thus has to be encoded separately.

So in your case you should first [parse the url using `java.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) and then encode each part accordingly for example using [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html).

You can also use `java.net.URI` for the encoding which also takes care of encoding each part separately but make sure to use `toASCIIString()` to get the proper encoded url as a string.